# c# Manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing an app using Azure WorkerRole and NServiceBus. When running I'm getting the following exception at runtime:

```
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while executing a resolve operation. See the InnerException for details. --->
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (See inner exception for details.) ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Spatial, Version=5.6.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) --->
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Spatial, Version=5.6.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

If I look at the properties of the reference to System.Spatial in VS I see Version 5.6.2.0

In my app.config file I have put the following:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
       <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="System.Spatial" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.2.0" newVersion="5.6.2.0" />
       </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
 </runtime>
```

But it didn't help.

How can I fix it or further diagnose what's missing?

Comment: Enabling automatic binding redirection might help. Give it a shot. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).